# Dynamic view title from node title

Tags: views

How to set a view title from page title dynamically, as if the page node title is About the Company I want the corresponding view title to be the same as node title.

any suggestions

Comment: Are you talking about a views block that is displayed on the same page as your node?

Comment: Are you using the view as page or block?

Comment: No it is not on the same page, I am using a view block for a page or lets say for a node of a content type in another page such as main page.

Answer (score 7):

Hope this will help  you.

In Drupal 7 you can use **VIEWS CONTEXTUAL FILTER** for your requirement

Steps

- Add **VIEWS contextual filter** for node ID

  [image: Contextual filter for node ID] item
- **Contextual filter settings** for node ID

  - Provide the **default argument** from the URL
  - Also **override** the **TITLE** and the **BREADCRUMB**

  [image: Contextual filter settings for node ID]
- Open browser and type **Base_url/view_path/NODE_ID** you can see both the **TITLE** and the **BREADCRUMB** will be changed based on the **NODE ID**.

Comment: Good idea but if one doesnt want the filter to limit results, they can select Global:Null filter. That filter doesnt filter results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars)` function in your theme's `template.php`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on *how* to use this hook for desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

From the Context part of the panel page pick out **%node:title** and put it in the settings of the view.